# How Do I add the small caps for the section?

Tags: sectioning, titlesec, small-caps

Here is an example that I'm trying to copy, I don't want the roman numerals, just the small caps, the aim is to make it look identical to the paper.

Mine: [image]

The Aim: [image]

My code is shown below:

```
%++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
% Don't modify this section unless you know what you're doing!
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % improve math presentation
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{graphicx} % takes care of graphic including machinery
\usepackage[margin=0.6in,letterpaper]{geometry} % decreases margin
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{cite} % takes care of citations
\usepackage[final]{hyperref} % adds hyper links inside the generated pdf file
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\cfoot{}
\lhead{Physics HL}
\rhead{Internal Assessment}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage[skip=10pt plus1pt, indent=40pt]{parskip}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,positioning,patterns,angles,quotes}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\Large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\section}{\Large\bfseries}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,       % false: boxed links; true: colored links
    linkcolor=blue,        % color of internal links
    citecolor=blue,        % color of links to bibliography
    filecolor=magenta,     % color of file links
    urlcolor=blue         
}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1} 
%++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
    \line(1,0){300} \\
    [0.25in]
    \huge{\bfseries INTERNAL ASSESSMENT} \\
    [2mm]
    \line(1,0){200} \\
    [1.5cm]
    \textsc{\LARGE What is the effect of varying the } \\
    [0.75cm]
    \textsc{\Large Pages: 12} \\
    [9cm]
\end{center}
\begin{flushright}
\\~\\ \\~\\ \\~\\ \\~\\ \\~\\ \\~\\ 
\textsc{\large Neal B.\\
IB HL Physics\\}
\end{flushright}
\end{titlepage}


\section{Exploration}
\subsection{Introduction}
During my early years of learning to play the flute, I struggled with maintaining a consistent tempo. Fortunately, I discovered the metronome, a device that produces a regular and precise beat, which helped me improve my sense of rhythm. This experience sparked my curiosity about the metronome's functionality, leading me to learn that it operates as a physical pendulum. Additionally, the study of physical pendulums also serves as a crucial precursor to understanding the unpredictable nature of double pendulums, which consist of two physical pendulums attached together. This topic is closely related to chaos theory, which is the modern successor to Newtonian mechanics. Despite being a common sight in clocks and musical instruments, double pendulums are incredibly complex and have defied attempts by physicists to develop an analytical solution. To grasp the intricacies of their chaotic mechanics, it is necessary to first examine the properties of the simpler correspondent, the physical pendulum.
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you (a) load the `fontenc` package with option [T1] and (b) change the instructions

```
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\Large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\section}{\Large\bfseries}
```

to

```
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\Large\bfseries\centering\scshape}
\titleformat*{\section}{\Large\bfseries\centering\scshape}
```

Actually, since your code loads the `ragged2e` package, you could use `\Centering` instead of `\centering`. (The difference between the effects of `\centering` and `\Centering` will become readily apparent if a section header is longer than a line.)

If you're guessing that `scshape` is short for "small caps shape", you would be correct.

[image]

---

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
%% (I've streamlined and simplified the OP's code as much as possible)
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % <-- new
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}

\usepackage[margin=0.6in,letterpaper]{geometry}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\large\bfseries\centering\scshape}
\titleformat*{\section}{\Large\bfseries\centering\scshape}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\cfoot{}
\lhead{Physics HL}
\rhead{Internal Assessment}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}

\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage[skip=10pt plus1pt, indent=40pt]{parskip}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{Exploration}
\subsection{Introduction}

\lipsum[1-2] % filler text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, this is amazing thank you. Though, when I apply that my text becomes blurry, especially in the title page. When looking for solutions, I saw to use \usepackage{lmodern} but when doing that, the document looked the same as the start.

Comment: @NealBatra -  Not sure what to say, as the screenshot of the output produced by the code shown above is *not* blurry. The blurriness present in your output must be due to some property of your code that I don't know anything about.

Comment: Ok, I will fix that myself. Thank you so so much though. Still a beginner to LaTeX as a high school student.